Webpack raw-loader/style-loader importing CSS file as JavaScript string instead of CSS content
I am using Webpack to build my chrome extension and I am trying to import a CSS file as a string so that I can inject it into a shadow DOM. However, when I import the CSS file, it is imported as JavaScript code instead of the CSS content.
The contents of the imported CSS string.
import css from './content.styles.css';
console.log(css);

    import API from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
      import domAPI from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
      import insertFn from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";
      import setAttributes from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/setAttributesWithoutAttributes.js";
      import insertStyleElement from "!../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js";
....
....


Here is my webpack config

{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/Content'),
  use: [
    'raw-loader',
    {
      loader: 'style-loader',
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        postcssOptions: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}

it was working fine until yesterday, I didn't make any changes to the config. This happened randomly after I did npm build on the project, and now every time I start the project, I get the same result. It has happened before but I thought I'd fixed it.
Things I've tried, but don't work

Switched the order of loaders
removed all loaders and only used raw-loaders (this imports CSS, but tailwind @import directives are ignored and tailwind isn't bundled in the final file.)
If I remove style-loader and keep css-loader and postcss-loader, I also get js in the imported string.

Just a note - I've got two rules using the above config. The first rule is for a specific folder and the other rule is for the rest of the files/folders. In the 2nd rule, I specifically exclude  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/Content') so that it doesn't conflict with the first.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

I managed to solve the problem with a little bit of tinkering.
I removed style-loader and CSS-loader rules. It seems like it was interpreting the @import in CSS as JS and injecting JS into the final string. Now it works like a charm.
So for anyone in the future looking for an answer to this, just keep 'raw-loader' and 'postcss-loader' loader (for tailwind)
